# javascript - input type = radio disappears when changing text

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

Im trying to change the text of a radio button.
In the beginning I got this:
[image]

but when I change the text with jquery I get this:
[image]

I tried `$('label[for=id_players_choice_0]').text(x)` and `$('#id_players_choice_0').text(x)` when x is my new value.

Comment: please, don't post code as image, post the actual code

Comment: `text()` does not set the `value=""` of an input.  `val()` does

Comment: The issue is because you've used `text()` which overwrite all the content in the element, including other child elements. I'd suggest wrapping the `A` in a `span` and setting `text()` on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see here http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2, jQuery text method changes the content of element. It results in removing all child elements and replacing it with the value of the parameter `string` used in `text(string)` method.
You should put the text content into separate element and edit its value by the `text()` method.

For example create a `span` element inside the label and use `$('label[for=id_players_choice_0] span').text(x)`